# Cull behind geometry to transparent

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to do a NPR render of a group of cats/objects and I want to render it once from the front and once from the back.

Right now it is all composed in one scene.

The tricky thing is that it need to be culled in the middle.

So far i tried to do it with a "cut"-plane and shader magic, but i'm not really a shader wizard, unfortunately...

**The desired cull plane**
[image]

**Cull Plane should work from behind as well**
[image]
**What I tried**

I know how to  achieve a transparent BG via the film color settings and I even tried a greenscreen approach with ChromaKey in the compo, but  there is a better way, I'm sure....
Blender gurus??

Can I cull something to transparency by geometry or is there another trick available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want clip-plane transparency like that, you can use object coordinates.z to mix in transparency, like

[image]

The plane is a basic old plane with a transparent material; you can see its axes in the solid viewport.  The texture coordinate node specifies that we want object coordinates from that plane.  Everything in front of the plane gets drawn like this.  To reverse it, change the math/less than node into a math/greater than node.

If you're rendering in Eevee, like I am, you'll want to make sure to set your material's blend and shadow mode in settings.  Alpha clip makes the most sense for this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation! The node system is so mighty, sometimes I just don't see the simple solutions. Thank you!